# Using Friendship on Opposed Challenges

Tags: tails-of-equestria

**What is the result when a PC uses 3 Tokens of Friendship to automatically pass an Opposed Challenge roll where the results of the dice rolls are important?**

The rules state that a PC may spend 3 Tokens of Friendship in order to simply outright succeed at any check, including opposed challenges between two characters (emphasis mine):

> By giving back 3 Tokens of Friendship to the GM, you pass the test or **win the challenge** automatically - **no re-roll** is needed!

However, in many opposed challenges, **the result of the die roll** and/or the difference between the dice rolls of the opposed parties **is significant.**  Examples include the amount of damage done while Scuffling (equal to the die roll of the winner) or the damage from a Stun Ray (equal to the difference of the two die rolls).

How are these effects resolved without the appropriate dice rolls?  Some possibilities include:

- The PC acts as if they rolled a max roll of 20 on a d20, the highest die size normally allowed.
- The PC acts as if they rolled a max roll on whatever size die they would normally be rolling for the check.
- The PC acts as if they rolled a-million-billion-infinity-plus-one and get the best result conceivable in reality.

In addition, whether or not the opposing party rolls their opposed dice is also a factor that can differ in each of these possibilities (though is irrelevant in the last case).

**How should such challenges be resolved?**

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those situations where the rules are genuinely unclear.

The most comprehensive house-rule answer, which I would probably go for, is that the person who redeemed the tokens beat the opposed roll by 1, no matter what - so victory is guaranteed, but no additional bonuses or damage are granted.  If you want extra results, you have to risk it and roll the dice.

If you feel this is unfair, however, the one true answer is "it's up to the DM's discretion".  Acting as though a nat 20 was rolled is perfectly valid.